# Javascript Date Eval Format

Tags: javascript, timestamp, format, eval

I have a javascript to return via eval the date of today in YYYY-MM-D format

The code javascript is

```
var d= new Date(); var m=((d.getMonth()+1)<10)?'0'+(d.getMonth()+1):(d.getMonth()+1); d.getFullYear()+"-"+m+"-"+d.getDate();
```

This return the date format YYYY-MM-D

I need to have the format DD-MM-YYYY

Example of date April, 7 2019

Actual: 2019-04-7 (US format)

Desidered: 07-04-2019 (UE format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will give your desired format.

```
var d= new Date(); var m=((d.getMonth()+1)<10)?'0'+(d.getMonth()+1):(d.getMonth()+1);var day=d.getDate()<10?'0'+d.getDate():d.getDate() ;day+"-"+m+"-"+d.getFullYear();
```

Comment: This code do not solve the problem, provider the same date format of my code example 7-04-2019 i need 07-04-2019 (DD-MM-YYYY) NOT (D-MM-YYYY)

Comment: @newuserkantu I updated my answer, it should be working now.

Comment: Thanks your new code like a charms, i accepted your answer, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can format function of momentjs library.

```
var expect = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY');
```

```js
var date= new Date();

var expect = moment(date).format('DD-MM-YYYY');

console.log(expect)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: I can not integrate this code because i need a javascript to integrate in a macro script and your code is incompatible

Comment: in that case, you need get day, month and year and concat string manually, you can refer this link https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-basic-exercise-3.php